# Pyinstaller: Fails to copy Python-can module on converting to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a script where we are using multiple imports as:

import re
import time
import easygui
import can
import threading

On Converting the script to exe using pyinstaller, it fails to include the can module and hence we get error as 'CAN module not found.

Need your inputs on how to resolve this

Comment: Where is your `can` module? Is it stored in the same place as the other ones or it's located in your project folder? In the latter case, you will have to specify the path to that folder in the `pathex` variable of PyInstaller.

Comment: The CAN module is stored in the site packages folder.